# Seeing $\mathbb{CP}^2 \mathbin\# \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ as a symplectic reduction of different manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties, symplectic-topology

I have been reading the paper "[Remarks on Lagrangian intersections on toric manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0640)" by Abreu and Macarini, which gives several non-displaceability results by avoiding the use of Lagrangian Floer theory just by doing symplectic reduction. However, I am having some trouble seeing why we can see certain manifolds as symplectic reduction. For example $\mathbb{CP}^2 \mathbin\# \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ as symplectic reduction of $\mathbb{CP}^2\times \mathbb{CP}^1$ or $\mathcal{O}(-1)\times \mathbb{CP}^2$. This is done on page 19 and they have some figures trying to explain the process, see figure 4. However I still don't have an intuitive idea of why this is true. What is happening behind these figures? For example in the case of seeing it as a symplectic reduction of $\mathbb{CP}^2\times \mathbb{CP}^1$ in figure 4 why do we need the two parallel dotted lines to make the cut?

In the right side corresponding to $\mathcal{O}(-1)\times \mathbb{CP}^2$ it just seems we are making a copy of the polygon of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ inside that of $\mathbb{CP}^2$, but in the left side we are taking two lines which wouldn't be taking a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ inside $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

So I am just confused on how we can see  $\mathbb{CP}^2 \mathbin\# \overline{\mathbb{CP}^2}$ as these symplectic reductions, and what is the idea behind those images. I can't tell if they are doing reduction by stages using the Delzant construction with the normals or not.

Edit: In the meantime, I spent a couple more hours thinking about this subject and I think I finally understand what is going on. This is just an application of the symplectic reduction the authors talk about in section $3$ where we know that the moment polytope for the resulting symplectic reduction is $P\subset (\mathbb{R}^n)^*\cong \ker i^*$, where $i$ is given by an inclusion of Lie algebras. We just need to choose the kernel to be appropriate so that we have the desired inequalities regarding the moment polytopes.

Comment: TeX note: $M \# N$ `M \# N` smooshes everything together, whereas $M \mathbin\# N$ `M \mathbin\# N` forces TeX to allocate space around the connected sum $\#$ as a binary operator.  I have edited accordingly.